# Замена текста в блоке2 при наведении на блок1

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

В jQuery есть установка текста элемента:

```
$(".span1").text("Заменяем текст с помощью jQuery");
```

Есть такой HTML-код:

```
<div class="box1" data-prise='2,5 x 1,5 200 300 400'></div>
<div class="box2" data-prise='3,5 x 2,5 300 400 500'></div>
<div class="box3" data-prise='4,5 x 3,5 400 500 600'></div>

<div>
    Размер <span class="s1">2,5 x 1,5</span>
    Цена 1 <span class="s2">200</span>
    Цена 2 <span class="s3">300</span>
    Цена 3 <span class="s4">400</span>
</div>
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при наведении на `div` с классом `box1` в `span` с классом `s1` вставлялся размер, в `span` с классом `sp2` вставлялась одна цена, в `sp3` - вторая, и в `sp4` - третья.

Размеры и информация каждого блока хранятся в `data-prise`.

Comment: Что вы пробовали сделать? Что не получилось? Всё есть в документации

Comment: Так я в JS просто не особо то и силён. По этому и пишу сюда, так как не знаю способа реализации.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В рамках существующего HTML-кода (если его вообще нельзя менять):

- Добавляем обработчик события наведения мыши `'mouseover'` для `.box1,.box2,.box3` (предполагаю, что нужно наведение не только на `.box1`).
- Берём значение `data-prise` (не знаю почему оно называется не `data-price`), делим его по пробелам, первые три части (например, `2,5 x 1,5`) объединяем обратно в одну. Можно было тот же результат получить через регулярное выражение.
- Устанавливаем полученные значения (`priceInfo`) в блоки `.s1` ... `.s4` с помощью обычного цикла.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.box1,.box2,.box3').on('mouseover', function() {
        var price = $(this).data('prise');
        var priceInfo = price.split(' ');
        priceInfo[0] = [priceInfo[0], priceInfo[1], priceInfo[2]].join(' ' );
        priceInfo.splice(1, 2);
        for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
            $('.s' + i).text(priceInfo[i - 1]);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="box1" data-prise='2,5 x 1,5 200 300 400'>box1</div>
<div class="box2" data-prise='3,5 x 2,5 300 400 500'>box2</div>
<div class="box3" data-prise='4,5 x 3,5 400 500 600'>box3</div>
<div>
    Размер: <span class="s1">2,5 x 1,5</span>
    Цена1: <span class="s2">200</span>
    Цена2: <span class="s3">300</span>
    Цена3: <span class="s4">400</span>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Что я бы изменил в HTML для упрощения кода:

- Классы у элементов `.box1`, `.box2` и `.box3` заменил на `.box`.
- Разбил `data-prise` на `data-size` и `data-prices`.
- Заменил `.s1` на `.size`, а `.s2`, `.s3` и `.s4` на `.price`.

В итоге код может выглядеть так:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $size = $('.size');
    var $prices = $('.price');
    $('.box').on('mouseover', function() {
        var size = $(this).data('size');
        var prices = $(this).data('prices').split(' ');
        $size.text(size);
        $prices.text(function(i) { return prices[i]; });
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="box" data-size='2,5 x 1,5' data-prices='200 300 400'>box1</div>
<div class="box" data-size='3,5 x 2,5' data-prices='300 400 500'>box2</div>
<div class="box" data-size='4,5 x 3,5' data-prices='400 500 600'>box3</div>
<div>
    Размер: <span class="size">2,5 x 1,5</span>
    Цена1: <span class="price">200</span>
    Цена2: <span class="price">300</span>
    Цена3: <span class="price">400</span>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Regent, большое спасибо. Великолепное решение. ОЧень благодарен тебе!

Comment: @RadCor на здоровье.